# How to make mosquitto_sub print ONLY current message when subscribed to one topic

Tags: cmd, mqtt, mosquitto

```
mosquitto_sub.exe -h host-p port -t topic-P password -u username  > log_file.txt
```

By using this command line all the message are saved in log_file.txt but how to save just the latest message to the log file .
As far as I know > works for overwriting the file , using this only at the start it overwrite the text file , after that it start appending all the messages in on file.

Answer (score 3):

mosquitto_sub has a command line option `-C` to control the number of messages to receive before existing.

```
mosquitto_sub.exe -h host-p port -t topic -P password -u username -C 1 > log_file.txt
```

From the mosquitto_sub [man](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html) page

> **-C**
>
> Disconnect and exit the program immediately after the given count of messages have been received. This may be useful in shell scripts
>   where on a single status value is required, for example.

Really ugly loop:

```
@echo off
:top:
mosquitto_sub.exe -h host-p port -t topic -P password -u username -C 1 > log_file.txt
goto top
```

Comment: This code is working fine. How can I use this in loop so that I don't have to type it again..

Answer (score 0):

You could embed the command in a for /f loop processing the output line by line overwriting the file content

```
@Echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
  mosquitto_sub.exe -h host -p port -t topic -P password -u username
') Do @Echo(%%A>log_file.txt
```

Comment: I replaced %% to % even then not working. log_file is not updating